# Drush Site-Aliases won't work

Tags: drush

I've been trying to set up some Drush aliases. However, when I try to run any command, it will echo the contents of all aliases files, and `drush sa` simply returns the contents of those files twice, and then the `@none`, `@self` and `@default` aliases (since I'm in the folder of a Drupal installation). When trying to run any command with an alias, e.g. `drush @local status`, I once again get a dump of those files, and finally a `Could not find the alias @local` error.

I've tried putting the aliases in `~/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php` and in `~/.drush/local.aliases.drushrc.php`. In the latter case, I tried two formats:

```
$aliases['local'] = array(
    'root' => '/home/user/subdomain/public_html',
    'uri' => 'subdomain.domain.com'
);
```

and

```
@code
    $options['uri'] = 'subdomain.domain.com';
    $options['root'] = '/home/user/subdomain/public_html';
@endcode
```

both without any different effect, apart from different contents being dumped. No other errors are thrown, it seems. I've also done a `drush cache-clear all` after each attempt.

Any thoughts as to what might cause this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error was quite simple; you forgot to put `<?php` at the top of your alias file.

Comment: Oh man. I simultaneously hope and really don't hope that is the case, but it makes a lot of sense. Will test in an hour or 2...

Comment: Wow! None of the tutorials that I read about the aliases file mentioned the need for the opening `<?php` tag but I guess that makes sense. THANK YOU.